# Calling a user defined function in a LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq

I've seen a few pages on the net regarding this, but unfortunately the sample code is in C#.  I can't make sense of most of it (and/or run it through a code translator) but I still need help making it work in VB.

My custom function is:

```
Public Shared Function GetFriendlyTitle(Title As String) As String
    Dim ConvertedTitle As String = ""
    Try
        Dim oRE As Regex = New Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]")
        ConvertedTitle = Trim(oRE.Replace(Title, "")).Replace(" ", "_")
    Catch ex As Exception
        LogError(ex)
    End Try
    Return ConvertedTitle
End Function
```

and here's the function I'm calling to return products:

```
Public Shared Function GetProductByTypeAndTitle(URLFriendlyTitle As String, ProductType As ProductType)
    Try
        'don't know why, but the server threw errors if I went c.Type=Type
        Dim pt As Integer = CInt([Enum].Parse(GetType(ProductType), [Enum].GetName(GetType(ProductType), ProductType)))

        Dim context As LionsSharePressEntities = New LionsSharePressModel.LionsSharePressEntities
        return From p In context.Products Where GetFriendlyTitle(p.Title) = URLFriendlyTitle AndAlso p.Type = pt
    Catch ex As Exception
        LogError(ex)
        Return nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

It compiles fine, but hangs when I run it.  It's that return line that does it.

Comment: I'm not strong in VB, but for me it looks like you missed return type in you GetProductByTypeAndTitle function definition.

Comment: just to note you, your `GetFriendlyTitle` function should be `return ConvertedTitle` instead of `return Title`. Shouldn't it?

Comment: You're right.  I just fixed it up, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737914#selsimp1) statement:

```
return From p In context.Products 
           Where GetFriendlyTitle(p.Title) = URLFriendlyTitle 
           AndAlso p.Type = pt 
           Select p
```

Comment: I just tried that and it came back with "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetFriendlyTitle(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old and already seems to have been resolved. But I'm still postings this in hopes that maybe it will help someone out with an alternate solution that has worked for me.

Also please note that I was not in a position to make my function called from w/in my LINQ query "Shared" making my situation slightly different. Which I thought all the more reason to post an alternate answer.

```
Public Function GetFriendlyTitle(Title As String) As String
    Dim ConvertedTitle As String = ""
    Try
        Dim oRE As Regex = New Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]")
        ConvertedTitle = Trim(oRE.Replace(Title, "")).Replace(" ", "_")
    Catch ex As Exception
        LogError(ex)
    End Try
    Return ConvertedTitle
End Function
```

When I ran into an issue calling a non shared user defined function from w/in a LINQ query this is how I resolved it using the OPs code snippet as an example.

```
Public Shared Function GetProductByTypeAndTitle(URLFriendlyTitle As String, _
                                                ProductType As ProductType)
    Try
        'don't know why, but the server threw errors if I went c.Type=Type
        Dim pt As Integer = _
                CInt([Enum].Parse(GetType(ProductType), _ 
                     [Enum].GetName(GetType(ProductType), ProductType)))
        Dim context As New LionsSharePressModel.LionsSharePressEntities

        '// Here is the lambda that will call your GetFriendlyTitle function
        Dim callUserFunc As Func(Of String, String) = _
                Function(title As String)
                    Return GetFriendlyTitle(title)
                End Function

        '// Now call Invoke on the lambda and pass in the needed param(s) from within your LINQ query
        return From p In context.Products _
               Where callUserFunc.Invoke(p.Title) = URLFriendlyTitle AndAlso p.Type = pt

        '//return From p In context.Products Where GetFriendlyTitle(p.Title) = URLFriendlyTitle AndAlso p.Type = pt

    Catch ex As Exception

        LogError(ex)
        Return nothing

    End Try
End Function
```